# What is the difference between Game Center and Apple Sign-in?

Tags: ios, game-center, apple-sign-in

Recently Apple released "**Sign in with Apple**" / **Apple Sign-in**. This will supported starting from firmware 13.

> https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/

As far as I remember, Apple also has "**Game Center**". The usage for this feature are includes saving game progress on cloud, Achievements, etc.

Android users might be familiar with **Google Play Games**. In Apple it was this "**Game Center**".

My question is, what is the difference between Apple Sign-in and Game Center? Is it only the firmware supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between Game Center and Apple Sign-in?

Well, **Game Center** is for games. While **Sign in with Apple** is for your usual applications. You wouldn't take an effort to integrate **Game Center** in your Enterprise, Banking, Social Media Apps, would you?

Furthermore, **Game Center** is basically Apple's social gaming network. It uses a framework called **Game Kit**.

What does **Game Kit** do?

> GameKit provides you with the ability to create apps that allow
>   players to interact with each other. Multiplayer apps allow your game
>   to create real-time network matches. Players can invite other players
>   to join their game. Most importantly, players can receive invitations
>   to join a match even when your game is not running. Your game is
>   running on each device and the instances of your game exchange match
>   and voice data with each other.

Lastly, **Sign in with Apple** is pretty much like your **Sign in with Facebook** or **Google Sign in**.

> Sign in with Apple allows you to set up a user account in your system,
>   complete with name, verified email address, and unique stable
>   identifiers that allow the user to sign in to your app with their
>   Apple ID. It works on iOS, macOS, tvOS, and watchOS. You can also add
>   Sign in with Apple to your website or versions of your app running on
>   other platforms. Once a user sets up their account, they can sign in
>   anywhere you deploy your app.

---

docs:

Game Center: https://developer.apple.com/game-center/

Game Kit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/

Sign in with Apple: https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/

Comment: So, basically we can say "Apple Sign-In" is like SNS (Social Network System) in Apple? It has "Friend" fetaure, no?